# Public url for file on server

Tags: php, .htaccess

I need some help to get public file from Apache server. I can get the file by urls like this:

```
http://localhost:8888/MyProject/rest/api/getimage?image=IMG_20140325_175015_743612961.jpg
```

But I want to get images by urls like this:

```
http://localhost:8888/MyProject/image/IMG_20140325_175015_743612961.jpg
```

I don't know how to do this. Path of images:

```
http://localhost:8888/MyProject/rest/api/uploads/
```

P.S: My example is a GET request but at the end of the project all requests will be POST request. And then I will never allow GET requests.

Comment: Which server ? if apache then use mod_rewrite. Here's generator tool http://www.generateit.net/mod-rewrite/index.php

Comment: @HardikThaker Apache server. My example is a GET request but at the end of the project all requests will be POST request. And then I never allow GET requests. Is this will still work?

Answer (score 1):

Symlink it -

`ln -s /path/to/webserver_root/MyProject/rest/api/uploads/* /path/to/webserver_root/MyProject/image/`

Answer (score 0):

Use Mod_Rewrite module in .htacess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>    
    RewriteEngine on    
    Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
    RewriteRule .* $0.php

    RewriteRule ^MyProject/image/([^/]*)$ MyProject/rest/api/getimage?image=$1 [L]
</ifModule>
```

This will redirect all the upcoming request in this format `http://localhost:8888/MyProject/image/IMG_20140325_175015_743612961.jpg`

to this one

`http://localhost:8888/MyProject/rest/api/getimage?image=IMG_20140325_175015_743612961.jpg`

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule .* $0.php
```

Note : The above code will allows to run your .php files without extension.

Now You need to write a script that catch $_GET['image'] variable at getimage.php file. So, do something there,

```
<?php
    if(isset($_GET['image'])) {
        $file = $_GET['image'];
        echo '<img src="http://localhost:8888/MyProject/rest/api/uploads/'.$file.'" />';
    }
    else {
        die('error');
    }
?>
```

Comment: I could not achieve my goal by this.